# How to output string list of an associative array?

Tags: php

I have an associative array:

```
$comboUserPosts = array();
array(
     'link'=> get_permalink(),
     'dates'=> $value,
     'title'=> get_the_title(),
     'id'=> $post->ID
)
```

I need to output all values of `id` like: `"232,555,797"`

I know I can do:

```
foreach ($comboUserPosts as $value) { 
    $value['id']
}
```

But I need to output that list of `ids` in the following, and obviously I cannot insert that within the `foreach` or it'll duplicate.

```
echo do_shortcode('[ajax_load_more pause="true" post_type="post" post__in="'.json_encode($comboUserPosts['id']).'" progress_bar="true" progress_bar_color="FF0080"]');
```

As you can see I tried using `json_encode($comboUserPosts['id'])` but it is not accessing that object

Comment: read about  implode function

Comment: @JYoThI I already tried to use `echo implode(",",$comboUserPosts['id']);` but where do I put that? if I put it within the do_short.. it won't work, as it cannot access the array and it says `Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in`

Comment: How about `echo implode(",",array_column($comboUserPosts,'id'));`?

Comment: @Eddie thanks a lot, it works. Put that into an answer and I'll accept it. BTW this is not the first time you resolved my issue with `array_column`, you must like it a lot :) I have to read in regards. Thanks again

Comment: lol. Kinda used it alot lately. It is very useful :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_column` to get the values from a single column from the input array

```
$comboUserPosts = array(
    array(
     'link'=> '',
     'dates'=> '',
     'title'=> '',
     'id'=> '1'
    ),
    array(
     'link'=> '',
     'dates'=> '',
     'title'=> '',
     'id'=> '2'
    )
);

echo implode( "," , array_column( $comboUserPosts , 'id' ) );
```

This will result to:

```
1,2
```

Doc: [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)